# How to share int between different methods java

Tags: java

Currently doing an assignment for uni where I have to create a sales page for tickets to the olympic. It's only basic but I was wondering how I could use the two `int`s `student` and `general` located in the purchase class in the menu class 
specifically for the view tickets section.

Here is my code below

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class modulisationtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i, user, general, student;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(i=1; i <=60;  i = i+1 )
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Federation University olympics 2016");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Developed by Ryan Guest, Student id 30285253 for Itech1000 ");
        System.out.println("");
        for(i=1; i <=60;  i = i+1 )
            System.out.print("*");  
        Menu();
    }


    public static void Menu() {
        int user;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Ticket Purchase Menu");
            System.out.println("1.Purchase");
            System.out.println("2.View Tickets");
            System.out.println("3.Exit");
            user = s.nextInt();

            switch (user)
            { 
            case 1: System.out.println("You have selected purchase"); Purchase();
            break;

            case 2: System.out.println("ticket");
            break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Thanks for shopping");
                System.exit(user);

            default: System.out.println("Not Valid");   
            }

        } while (user!=3);





    }       
    public static void Purchase() 

    {
        int user, general=0, student =0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Ticket Purchase Menu");
                System.out.println("1.General Admission");
                System.out.println("2.Student ticket");
                System.out.println("3.Finalise order");
                System.out.println("4.Return to Menu");
                user = s.nextInt();

                switch (user)
                { 
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("How many General tickets do you want to purchase");
                    general = s.nextInt();

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("How many student tickets do you want to purchase");
                    student = s.nextInt();

                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("You're Buying" + " " + general + " " + "General tickets and" + " " + student + " " + "Student Tickets");

                    break;


                case 4:
                    break;

                default: System.out.println("Not Valid");
                }


            } while (user!=3&&user!=4);




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of just calling `static` methods learn to create Objects which represent the data you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring 'int user, general=0, student =0;' in the function Purchase, declare them globally in the class, that way they can be accessed ANYWHERE in your code that isn't static(unless you change the identifier to static.

```
IMPORTS_HERE
class NAME{
    int user = 0, general = 0, student = 0;
    //CODE HERE
}
```

Pro-Tip: Always initialize a variable before using it, its good practice and some types require it. Also, don't declare a variable inside of a function, its bad practice since it reserves new memory every time you call that function! :D